# How can I do disk surface scanning, and fix/reallocate bad sectors in Linux from the command line?

Tags: hard-disk, fsck

I bought a disk with some bad sectors, planning to fix them and then use it as part of RAID 6 cluster. I can do bad sector fixing under Windows, there are very good bad block fixing tools, but under Windows, the process is very slow, one sector fix takes 15 minutes.

In my experience, Linux is better at dealing with devices that don't respond in time and this results in a far faster process under Linux. However, I checked the `fsck` manual, but did not find any useful option for surface & bad block scanning or bad block reallocation.

How can I scan the surface of my hard disk and fix/reallocate bad sectors in Linux from the command line?

Comment: Since a long, long time (decades), disks fix their own bad sectors unprompted. Operating systems don't even know the physical mapping of sectors on disk due to repair remapping performed by the drive firmware. Given that, should it not be sufficient to either (1) just let the drive notice the bad sectors and fix them when they get wrtritten, or (2) if you really want to, force every sector to be rewritten once with `dd if=/dev/zero` so that it happens sooner. So long as you are using the disk for new storage, not trying to read existing data on it that might be inaccessible, you should be fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*This answer is about magnetic disks. SSDs are different. Also, this is disk with no data (or no data you care to preserve) on it; see [my answer to “Can I fix bad blocks on my hard disk with a single command”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25934/977) for what to do if you have important data on the disk.*

Disks made since at least the late 90s manage bad blocks themselves. In brief, a disk will handle a bad block by transparently replacing it with a spare sector. It will do so if (a) while reading, it discovers the block is "weak", but ECC is enough to recover the data; (b) while writing, it discovers the sector header is bad; (c) while writing, if a read previously detected the sector as bad, but the data was not recoverable.

The disk firmware typically lets you monitor this process (the counts at least) via SMART attributes. Typically there will be at least a count of reallocated sectors and two counts of pending (discovered bad on read, ECC failed, has not yet been written to).

There are two ways to get the disk to notice bad sectors:

1. Use `smartctl -t offline /dev/sdX` to tell the disk firmware to do an offline surface scan. You then just leave the disk alone (completely idle will be fastest) until it's done (check the "Offline data collection status" in `smartctl -c /dev/sdX`). This will typically update the "offline uncorrectable" count in SMART. (Note: drives can be configured to automatically run an offline check routinely.)
2. Have Linux read the entire disk, e.g., `badblocks -b 4096 -c 1024 -s /dev/sdX`. This will typically update the "current pending sector" count in SMART.

Either of the above may also increase the reallocated sector count—this is case (b), the ECC recovered the data.

Now, to recover the sectors you just need to write to them. Normally, that'd be a simple `pv -pterba /dev/zero > /dev/sdX` (or just plain `cat`, or `dd`) ***but*** you plan to make these part of a RAID array. The RAID init will write to the entire disk anyway, so that's pointless. The only exception the beginning and end of the disk—it's possible a few tens of megabytes will be missed (due to alignment, headers, etc.). So:

```bash
disk=/dev/sdX
end=$(echo "$(/sbin/blockdev --getsize64 "$disk")/4096-32768" | bc)
dd if=/dev/zero bs=4096             count=32768 of="$disk"   # first 128 MiB
dd if=/dev/zero bs=4096 seek="$end" count=32768 of="$disk"   # last 128 MiB
```

I think I managed to avoid the all-to-easy fencepost error<sup>1</sup> above, so that should blank the first and last 128MiB of the disk. Then let mdadm raid init write the rest. It's harmless (except for trivial wear, and wasting hours of time) to zero the whole disk if you'd like to, though.

Another thing to do, if your disks support it: `smartctl -l scterc,40,100` (or whatever numbers) to tell the disk that you *want* it to give up on correcting read errors quicker—40 would be 4 seconds. The two numbers are read errors and write errors; mdraid will easily correct read errors via parity (and write the failed sector back to the disk to let it reallocate). Write errors, though, will fail the disk out of the array.

PS: Make sure to keep an eye on the reallocated sectors count. That attribute going to failed is bad news. And if its continuously increasing, that's bad news too.

PPS: Make sure your RAID arrays are scrubbed (every sector read and all the parity verified) routinely. Many distros already ship a script that does this monthly. This will detect & repair any new bad blocks as otherwise seldom-read bad blocks can linger and ultimately cause rebuild failure.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Fencepost error—a type of off-by-one error from failing to count one of the ends. Named from *if you have a fence post every 3ft, how many fence posts in a 9ft freestanding fence?* The correct answer is 4; the fencepost error is 3 and is from not counting the post at the beginning or at the end.</sub>

Comment: How to "Make sure your RAID arrays are scrubbed"?

Comment: @klor On Debian (and probably most distros based on Debian), it's done via `/etc/cron.d/mdadm `. You need to check your distro's docs. But basically, something needs to write `check` to `/sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action` routinely ("routinely" being once or twice a month).

Comment: How do I *find* the reallocated sector count?  I saw some things in a SMART report which looked like they might be that but the numbers made no sense so I assume I was misreading something.

Answer (score 0):

If you have identified visible bad blocks, the disk is likely going bad very fast.  Unless you have an EXTREMELY old disk, bad block replacement is handled internally and you will not see them.  If you are seeing these, the replacement block cache has apparently been exhausted.

I would NOT use a disk in such a state and probably would wipe it and then toss it.

Comment: You will see them, as the disk can't reallocate a failed sector unless it's written to (unless it catches it early, and can recover the data using the ECC info). But if you ever see a bad block on *write*, that's a very bad sign.

Comment: See, for example, this answer on Serverfault from someone who (at least claims to) have written drive firmware: https://serverfault.com/questions/104417/how-do-i-easily-repair-a-single-unreadable-block-on-a-linux-disk/431051#431051